# serving files to angular app from file system on different server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have one server running the angular application and another one for the web api.

I have a mechanism to upload and save the photos path. For example, I store the path in my database:

`http://localhost:37020/App_Data/Tmp/FileUploads/248/tag2.png`

So, when I want to display those images, I use

```
<img ng-src="path">
```

but I get

> GET http://localhost:37020/App_Data/Tmp/FileUploads/248/tag2.png 404 (Not Found)
>
> HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment
>   section.

What i have done in my web api is set up a route like:

```
routeTemplate: "App_Data/Tmp/FileUploads/{listingId}/{file}"
```

but the controller doesnt seem to pick up the request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using App_Data folder.

Changing the folder worked just fine. I didnt even have to create a controller or action to serve the files